# laravel check for record existence before inserting, the efficient way

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let's say I have table named groups with these data:

```
+----+---------+------+-------+
| id | user_id | name | color |
+----+---------+------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | foo  | green |
|  2 |       1 | bar  | red   |
|  3 |       1 | baz  |       |
|  4 |       2 | baz  | grey  |
|  5 |       3 | foo  | blue  |
|  6 |       3 | baz  |       |
|  7 |       4 | baz  | brown |
|  8 |       4 | foo  |       |
|  9 |       4 | qux  | black |
+----+---------+------+-------+
```

I'm going to read a csv file and convert it to an array of data like this:

```
[
    [
        'user_id'   => 2,
        'name'      => 'foo'
    ],
    [
        'user_id'   => 2,
        'name'      => 'bar'
    ],
    [
        'user_id'   => 2,
        'name'      => 'baz'
    ],
    [
        'user_id'   => 2,
        'name'      => 'qux'
    ],
    [
        'user_id'   => 2,
        'name'      => 'tux'
    ],
]
```

and insert only new data into database, and skip what already exist in database, in this example, group `baz` for user 2.

In Eloquent there are some useful methods like `firstOrCreate()` or `findOrNew()` that seems to be what I need, but these methods are for only one record, and if I use them I should run them per file line.

```
while($line = $this->decoder->decode($this->file) {
    $row = Group::firstOrCreate($line);
}
```

Is there any better solution with running less queries?

Answer (score 2):

Use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
INSERT INTO table (user_id,name) VALUES(1, "test") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name)
```

For Laravel check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18846053/1237683)

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, `firstOrNew()` and `firstOrCreate()` is useful if I had single record, but I'm looking for a way to do it for multiple records.

Answer (score 1):

You can just load the file directly into a table and ignore duplicate entries. All you need is a unique index on the column which should not have duplicates. Then you do

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name.csv'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(user_id, @var)
SET name = do_some_voodoo(@var);
```

And that's it. Read more about this command [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

**Test:**

```
/*sample data*/
shell> cat test.csv
Name|Value
Anna|hello
Ben |Test
East|whatever
Anna|This line should be ignored
Bob |
```

---

```
/*creating destination table in database*/
mysql> create table phpload(a varchar(50) primary key, b varchar(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

---

```
/*Test script*/
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","r00t","playground");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/developer/test.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE phpload FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' (a, @b) SET b = UPPER(@b);";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

```
/*executing*/
shell> php test.php

mysql> select * from phpload;
+------+----------+
| a    | b        |
+------+----------+
| Name | VALUE    |
| Anna | HELLO    |
| Ben  | TEST     |
| East | WHATEVER |
| Bob  |          |
+------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Works absolutely fine.

Comment: Cool, but the problem is I have to do some process and validation and etc. on each line

Comment: Not really, I don't have access to SQL level

Comment: @Behzadsh Updated my answer to prove that it's working absolutely fine and you can work with it without "SQL level".