# Saving one to one relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

A `User` has one (or zero) `Company`, and a `Company` belongs to one and only one `User`. I try to save a company for a user but it adds a new entry in database every time I re-trigger the save method. It's a one to one relation, so I though `save` method on `User`.

So `Company` has one method `user()`:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

And `User` has one method `company()`:

```
public function company() {
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class, 'user_id');
}
```

I'm trying to save (so create or update) a user's company like this (in a Controller):

```
$company = new Company();
$company->name = 'Test';
User::findOrFail(1)->company()->save($company);
```

First time I run this code it creates the entry in database (OK), but second time it adds a new entry for the same user (Not OK). I thought it will only update the database entry.

Is it a glitch (or something I don't understand in one to one relation) in Laravel or **am I doing something wrong?** (I think and hope it's the second purpose)

Comment: Check this answer, it might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20764237/5122070

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure it really helps for this particular problem. My problem is more specific. It's about saving (creating or updating) directly in relation

Comment: @rap-2-h Mihkel Allorgs reference was correct. One can use the `updateOrCreate` method also on relationships. This is the best way to do it. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56002200/2311074

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Creating and updating need to treat differently. So check the existence of company attribute first.

```
$user = User::with('company')->findOrFail(1);
if ($user->company === null)
{
    $company = new Company(['name' => 'Test']);
    $user->company()->save($company);
}
else
{
    $user->company->update(['name' => 'Test']);
}
```

Note that `hasOne()` does not guarantee that you will have one-to-one relationship, it just telling Eloquent how to create query. It works even you have multiple `Company` refer to same `User`, in such case when you call `$user->company` you will get first `Company` in the result data set from database.

Comment: Ok thanks. "Note that hasOne() does not guarantee that you will have one-to-one relationship, it just telling Eloquent how to create query" -> Very helpful, It's clear enough now.

Answer (score 31):

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
$company = $user->company ?: new Company;
$company->name = 'Test';
$user->company()->save($company);
```

Comment: Like this way too! Quick and clean! +1 :)

Answer (score 17):

> I'm trying to save (so create or update) a user's company

You can do exactly that with the [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods) method:

```
User::findOrFail(1)->company()->updateOrCreate([],['name' => 'xyz']);
```

The first parameter of `updateOrCreate` is an empty array, because the companies `id` is determined by the `hasOne` relationship `$user->company()`.

And by the way, I would recommend not using an auto-increment id field in a `hasOne` relationship. If you set `user_id` as primary in your company table, its technically not possible to create duplicate company rows for one user.