# Check if exist and create

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try generate and save uncial slug for title in DB.

```
                $feed->friendlyUrl()->make([
                'url' => str_slug($feed->name),
                'action' => "feeds/{$feed->id}",
                'complicated' => false,
                'page_type_id' => PageType::TYPE_INDIVIDUAL_FEED_PAGE,
            ]);
```

How check if such field in url exist? And if exist save:

```
'url' => str_slug($feed->name,"-1"),
```

I think:

```
  if (FriendlyUrl::whereUrl(str_slug($feed->name))){
            $feed->friendlyUrl()->make([
                'url' => str_slug($feed->name),
                'action' => "feeds/{$feed->id}",
                'complicated' => false,
                'page_type_id' => PageType::TYPE_INDIVIDUAL_FEED_PAGE,
            ]);} else {
                $feed->friendlyUrl()->make([
                    'url' => str_slug($feed->name),
                    'action' => "feeds/{$feed->id}-1",
                    'complicated' => false,
                    'page_type_id' => PageType::TYPE_INDIVIDUAL_FEED_PAGE, 
            };
            break;
```

But it not clean and what if such url - `str_slug($feed->name,"-1")` already exists?

Comment: Please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839941/insert-a-new-record-if-not-exist-and-update-if-exist-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
$friendlyUrl = friendlyUrl::firstOrNew(
    ['url' => str_slug($feed->name,"-1")], [
                'action' => "feeds/{$feed->id}",
                'complicated' => false,
                'page_type_id' => PageType::TYPE_INDIVIDUAL_FEED_PAGE,]
);

$friendlyUrl->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unique slug for title

```
public static function boot()
           {
               parent::boot();

           static::creating(function($model) {
               $model->slug = str_slug($model->ToBeSluggified);// change the ToBeSluggiefied

               $latestSlug =
                   static::whereRaw("slug = '$model->slug' or slug LIKE '$model->slug-%'")
                       ->latest('id')
                       ->value('slug');
               if ($latestSlug) {
                   $pieces = explode('-', $latestSlug);

                   $number = intval(end($pieces));

                   $model->slug .= '-' . ($number + 1);
               }
           });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$FriendlyUrl = FriendlyUrl::firstOrNew(array('url' => str_slug($feed->name)));
$FriendlyUrl->action = "feeds/{$feed->id}";
$FriendlyUrl->complicated = false;
$FriendlyUrl->page_type_id = PageType::TYPE_INDIVIDUAL_FEED_PAGE;
$FriendlyUrl->save();
```

Reference - 
[Insert a new record if not exist and update if exist, laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839941/insert-a-new-record-if-not-exist-and-update-if-exist-laravel-eloquent)