# Eloquent - fields that match in a record if firstOrNew fails with multiple conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

Suppose I have the following create code

```
$User = User::firstOrNew(
  array(
    'username' => $args['username'],
    'phone_no' => $args['phone_no']
  ),
  array(
    'otherDetails' => 'here',
  )
);

$User->save();

if (!$User->wasRecentlyCreated) {
  // code to check which field has same record in db    
}
```

After confirming that the insertion was not able to push through because an existing record has been fetched, is there any way I can find out which of either ***username*** or ***phone_no*** has the same data in the User table? Without using another **where** lookup in the model. Thanks.

Comment: Since `username` and `phone_no` are in the first array of `firstOrNew`, the answer is both. If a record exists in your database with the same `username`/`phone_no` pair; then it is returned for you and you can access it as `$User`.

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/21009418/4575350

Comment: Hi @leek, does that mean that the first argument of `frstOrNew` will work something like `WHERE username = ? AND phone_no = ?`. How about if we want to know if either of the fields already existed? Thank you, I'm new to Laravel - eloquent and its docs.

Comment: @rhanmiano Correct. To do what you're asking, you are better off just querying `WHERE username = ? OR phone_no = ?`. If no record is returned, then you can proceed with creating one.